# Java design question: sharing information between objects

Tags: java

Some general java design question.

I have a main class "Telegram" (it generates XML-Telegrams - just to give some context)

In the course of working, a telegram object creates other objects (lets call them detail objects) of different classes to build up all the data that finally go into the XML-File. Now there's some steering information of how this information is to be gathered which also has to be communicated to some of the other objects. For instance at the moment there is a method in the telegram class which tells us, if a specific behaviour should be taken or not. These kind of exceptional behaviours might get more over time.

So I was wondering: should I put a reference of the central telegram object (aka "this") to all subsequently created detail objects, so the detail objects can question the telegram object about the steering information? Or should I transmit this steering information in form of specific parameters? Or is there a kind of design pattern for this type of task which I have overlooked? What would be the most elegant but also practical way of doing this? Ideas?

Comment: You are doing a cyclic dependency. This is a common design mistake. 
Since we don't know in detail your small objects that the Telegram class is creating,
I suggest to refactor the information you want to spread in a DTO object and inject it later.

Answer (score 1):

Giving the other objects an instance of the telegram class ("this" keyword) should work fine,  if you did not want to do it like that, then you create a Handle class that just sends information back and forth from other classes. The handler class does need an instance of the Telegram class though and all the objects sending information need the same handler class instance.